# Components are maximizing but not moving to TOP

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I'm making one jInternalFrame where I'am adding tabs dynamically.

now adding a new TAB I have coded,

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameEvent;
import javax.swing.event.InternalFrameListener;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI;

/**
 *
 * @author santoshg
 */
public class jTAB extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form jTAB
     */
    JTabbedPane tabList = new JTabbedPane();
    int nUserCount = 1;
    boolean isDrag = true;
    private static int pressedX = 0, pressedY = 0;
    JDesktopPane sDesktoppane = new JDesktopPane();
    JComponent northPane;

    public jTAB() {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        initComponents();
        drag();

        jInternalFrame1.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equalsIgnoreCase("maximum")) {
                    if (jInternalFrame1.isMaximum()) {
                        try {                                           // Maximizing TAB window with the size of Screen.
                            jInternalFrame1.setMaximum(true);
                            Toolkit tk = getToolkit();
                            jInternalFrame1.setSize((int) getToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(), (int) getToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight());
                            setLocation(0, 0);
                            isDrag = false;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {                                           // Setting it to it's actual size.
                            jInternalFrame1.setMaximum(false);
                            jInternalFrame1.setSize(jInternalFrame1.preferredSize());
                            isDrag = true;
                            setLocation(pressedX, pressedY);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public final void drag() {
        setContentPane(sDesktoppane);
        jInternalFrame1.setSize(jInternalFrame1.preferredSize());
        jInternalFrame1.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameListener() {
            @Override
            public void internalFrameOpened(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameClosed(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameIconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
                jInternalFrame1.setIconifiable(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameDeiconified(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameActivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void internalFrameDeactivated(InternalFrameEvent e) {
            }
        });

        jInternalFrame1.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getPropertyName().equalsIgnoreCase("maximum")) {
                    if (jInternalFrame1.isMaximum()) {
                        try {                                           // Maximizing TAB window with the size of Screen.
                            jInternalFrame1.setMaximum(true);
                            Toolkit tk = getToolkit();
                            jInternalFrame1.setSize((int) getToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(), (int) getToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight());
                 `enter code here`           setLocation(0, 0);
                            isDrag = false;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {                                           // Setting it to it's actual size.
                            jInternalFrame1.setMaximum(false);
                            jInternalFrame1.setSize(jInternalFrame1.preferredSize());
                            isDrag = true;
                            setLocation(pressedX, pressedY);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        if (northPane == null) {
            northPane = ((BasicInternalFrameUI) jInternalFrame1.getUI()).getNorthPane();
            northPane.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (isDrag) {
                        System.out.println("pressedX and pressedY " + pressedX + " " + pressedY);
                        pressedX = e.getX();
                        pressedY = e.getY();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                }
            });

            northPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (isDrag) {
                        int draggedObjX = getLocation().x + e.getX() - pressedX;
                        int draggedObjY = getLocation().y + e.getY() - pressedY;
                        setLocation(draggedObjX, draggedObjY);
                        getjInternalFrame().setLocation(0, 0);
                    }
                }

                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                }
            });
        }
        sDesktoppane.add(jInternalFrame1);
        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);
        jInternalFrame1.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                setSize(jInternalFrame1.getSize().width, jInternalFrame1.getSize().height);
            }
        });

        setSize(jInternalFrame1.getSize());
        if (northPane == null) {
            setLocation(new Point(pressedX, pressedY));
        }
        super.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JInternalFrame getjInternalFrame() {
        return jInternalFrame1;
    }

    public JComponent getNorthPane() {
        return northPane;
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jInternalFrame1.setMaximizable(true);
        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        jButton1.setText("Add TAB");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 512, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jInternalFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(0, 301, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jInternalFrame1)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

        tabList.addTab("User " + nUserCount, new ChatWindow("user " + nUserCount).getFrameComponent());
        JComponent jif = (JComponent) jInternalFrame1.getContentPane();
        jif.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jif.add(tabList);
        nUserCount++;
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(jTAB.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new jTAB().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Where ChatWindow,java is

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ui;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
 *
 * @author santoshg
 */
public class ChatWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form ChatWindow
     */
    public ChatWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public ChatWindow(String userName) {

        initComponents();
        lblUserName.setText(userName);
    }

    public JComponent getFrameComponent(){
        return jPanel1;
    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lblUserName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblAvatar = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        lblUserDept = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblContactInfo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblSendFile = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lblUserName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        lblUserName.setText("UserName");
        lblUserName.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);

        lblAvatar.setText("Avatar");
        lblAvatar.setAlignmentX(0.5F);
        lblAvatar.setAlignmentY(0.2F);
        lblAvatar.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
        lblAvatar.setIconTextGap(2);
        lblAvatar.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(35, 15));

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(249, 251, 252));
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(2);
        jTextArea2.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(3, 22));
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        lblUserDept.setText("Department");

        lblContactInfo.setToolTipText("User Info");

        lblSendFile.setToolTipText("Send File");

        jLabel1.setToolTipText("View History");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblAvatar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(lblUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 213, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(lblUserDept, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 355, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(lblContactInfo)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblSendFile)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblUserName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblContactInfo)
                                .addComponent(lblSendFile))
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblUserDept))
                    .addComponent(lblAvatar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 50, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 243, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 383, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChatWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblAvatar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblContactInfo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblSendFile;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblUserDept;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblUserName;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Hit the add button twice you'll get 2 TABS not when I maximize it "Add TAB" moved to Middle and Textareas are in top.

I want jTextAtrea1 to expand till the bottom of the page during maximize and restore to actual size during toggle.

[image]

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Seems problem with `LayoutManager`, post MCVE for help.

Comment: okay, I have added full code, let me know if I'm wrong or still missing something

Answer (score 0):

> I want jTextAtrea1 to expand till the bottom of the page during maximize

Sounds like you should be using a BorderLayout for the panel you add to the tab. Then you add the text area to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` and the other components to the `BorderLayout.NORTH`.

It looks like your layout code is generated by an IDE. Don't use the IDE to generate layout code. Do the layout yourself and you will be in full control.